# Display discount ad when people visit the page

Tags: javascript, advertising

A client of mine wants to display a discount advert on top of the site when user visited the page, so I imagine it will be triggered by the onload handler of my front page.  I thought I can display the ad content in a colorbox to raise it even more above the content. How can I trigger a colorbox to show up with the onload handler of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Splash Offer](https://drupal.org/project/splash_offer) module. It will show the popup on page load.

> Allows the management of one or more "splash offers", which are modal
>   popups with an accept or reject form. If a user accepts the offer then
>   a new page will open with a provided accept url. If they reject the
>   offer, the modal will close. (If they select Do not Show Again, then a
>   cookie is set so as to avoid further display.) You may define the who,
>   when and where of the splash offers with precision controls. Factors
>   such as: user role, site url, device, and whether the offer has been
>   previously viewed (cookies), cookie duration, etc. are configurable
>   for each splash offer created.

also take a look at this modules - [Splashify](https://drupal.org/project/splashify), [Splash](https://drupal.org/project/splash) and [TinyBox (Simple Splash)](https://drupal.org/project/tinybox).